# Is this a property of isomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

In a homework problem I was doing, I was trying to show that $U(8)$ is not isomorphic to $U(10)$. They used that, supposing $f: U(10) \rightarrow U(8)$ was an isomorphism, $|f(3)| = |3| = 4$ and there are no elements of order $4$ in $U(8)$, thus disproving that any such isomorphism could exist.

I am confused. For a given homomorphism $\varphi : G \rightarrow H$, I understand it is true that $|\varphi(x)|$ divides $|x|$, for some $x\in G$.

For an **isomorphism** $\varphi : G \rightarrow H$, is it the case that $|\varphi(x)| = |x|$, for $x\in G$?

If not, can you explain the reasoning in the proof given at the beginning?

Comment: It is the case that for an isomorphism $\phi:G\to H$, $|\phi(x)|=|x|$ for $x\in G$.

Comment: Thank you Tanner

Comment: To quickly see this using the facts you already know, note that given $\phi$, you know $|\phi(x)|$ divides $|x|$, but since its an isomorphism, you have a map in the opposite direction too so $|x|$ divides $|\phi(x)|$, so $|\phi(x)| = |x|$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you, Osama.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the case that for an isomorphism $\phi:G\to H$, $|\phi(x)|=|x|$ for $x\in G$.